# How to update children rows of an object that has OneToMany association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

I am working on a Java project, and I got stuck while trying to update an object with a oneToMany association, here are my classes :

**Team.class**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TEAM", schema = SchemaRef.NOM_SCHEMA_REF)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = CacheRegion.CACHE_TEAM)
    public class TEAM extends TeamPrincipal {

        /**
         * long serialVersionUID.
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7697301560938121726L;

        /** The players . */
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tm", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = CacheRegion.CACHE_TEAM)
        private Set<Player> listPlayers;

//Getters & Setters

    }
```

**Player.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYER", schema = SchemaReferentiel.NOM_SCHEMA_REF)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = CacheRegion.CACHE_TEAM)
public class Player extends DomainObject {

    /**
     * long serialVersionUID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7697301560938121726L;

    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
                       name = "SequenceIdGenerator",
                       sequenceName = SchemaReferentiel.NOM_SCHEMA_REF + ".SEQUENCE_PLAYER",
                       allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SequenceIdGenerator")
    @Column(name = "PLAYER_ID")
    private long id;

    /** The Player. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lTeam_Player", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "C_FK_PlTeam_Player")
    private Team team;

//getters and setter
}
```

The calling DAO method is **TeamDao.java**:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(toSave);
```

The problem I am facing with this mapping is when I try to update the Team by changing the list of players it updates the **Team** attributes but the **Players** are always the same as when it was added.

The creation is done correctly, in debug mode while trying to update, the team contains the new list of players to update, after the call of DAO method, the parent(**TEAM**) is updated but the children (**Players**) are not

Answer (score 0):

As this is a bi-directional mapping, make sure that you set the players for a team and set the team for each of the players:

```
team.setPlayers(players);

for(Player player: players){
   player.setTeam(team);
}

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(team);
```

Comment: Thank you #Maciej Kowalski I did it, but no changes, the children rows are still ignored.